# URI's to fetch database data (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

So I'm trying to utilise CodeIgniter's URI segment functionality. I have the URI segments being used as ids to retrieve information from the database.
It's working fine, but I have noticed that if I put in an id that doesn't exist in the database, it spits out a database error.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Model Code:

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('questions')
    ->where('questions.id', $question_id)
    ->join('users', 'users.id = questions.user_id')
    ->get();
return $query->row();
```

Call to model in controller:

```
$question_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$data['question'] = $this->forum_model->get_question($question_id);
```

PHP error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: show some code on how you retrieve the data and also the database error message

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the query returned any results before calling $query->row

The way to do it is:

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('questions')
    ->where('questions.id', $question_id)
    ->join('users', 'users.id = questions.user_id')
    ->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
          return $query->row();
    else
          return false;
```

$query->num_rows() will give you the number of rows returned.

Comment: So I tried this, but it still gave me the same error. Is it because the function is still trying to grab a value that doesn't exist from the controller? How would I do a check in the function to make sure this doesn't happen?

Comment: @Sneaksta $query->num_rows() should be enough of a check to make sure you got results back. Can you give more details about the error and what is throwing the error?

Comment: Well putting an invalid character in was messing it up. I just made a simple function now that checks the characters that are inputted and makes sure they are normal, then sends a default value if they aren't.

Comment: But that still isn't sufficient... It's because in my view file, I'm trying to grab variables that aren't coming through because of the error. What do I do to prevent this?

Comment: If the problem is in your view, in your model return false if there are no results, and in the view, if $question is false, display an error message.

Answer (score 0):

to debug just do this...

```
    //if this gives u no result, then thats the problem because it couldnt find the 
    //$this->uri->segment(3);
$question_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
echo $question_id; 

//if this prints out the expected result.
//then you should know that the problem is still somewhere down the code.
$data['question'] = $this->forum_model->get_question($question_id);
var_dump($data['question']);


//this is for your model.
echo $question_id
$query = $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('questions')
    ->where('questions.id', $question_id)
    ->join('users', 'users.id = questions.user_id')
    ->get();
return $query->row();
```

NOTE: if all this echos outputs valid values, then check somewhere else for the problem